# Jquery : Access data-link attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i want to get data-link attribute form an image click .

Following is my image tag

```
<a href="#"  class="aclick">
    <img data-link="petroliumjelly.php" src="productsimgs/petroliumjelly.png" class="img-responsive" id="2">
</a>
```

to get it on click this is what i am doing ,

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
       $(".aclick").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        alert($(this).attr("data-link"));
        var link = $(this).data("data-link");// tried both 
        console.log(link);

    });

</script>
```

when i try to log or alert it, i get undefined 
Please help me how can i fix it

Comment: try this,  alert($(".img-responsive").attr("data-link"));

Comment: FYI, I removed the PHP tag since this question has nothing to do with PHP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is code snippet to help you. data-link attribute is in img tag and not in 'a' tag.

```js
$(".aclick").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        alert($(this).find('img').attr("data-link"));
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#"  class="aclick">
    <img data-link="petroliumjelly.php" src="productsimgs/petroliumjelly.png" class="img-responsive" id="2">
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason you're not getting a value is that you're getting the data-link attribute of the anchor tag as that is what represents this.  If you find the child image you'll get the data-link.  Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/q1kq4z5n/) of it working.

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
       $(".aclick").click(function (e) {
             e.preventDefault();
             alert($(this).find('img').attr('data-link'));
             var link = $(this).find('img').attr('data-link')
             console.log(link);

       });

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this,

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
     $(".aclick").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        alert($(this).find('img').attr('data-link'));
        var link = $(this).find('img').attr('data-link')
        console.log(link);    
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

In the context, `$(this)` refers to the link, not the image.

To get the image instead, use:

```
var link = $('img', $(this)).data('link');
```

That gets the `img` element inside the link (which is `$(this)`).

Read more about the `.data()`-method here: https://api.jquery.com/data/
In my opinion, it makes it a bit cleaner than using the `.attr()`-method.

Answer (score 0):

You assign you data-link attribute in img tag,

so you have to write click event on img tag

```js
    $(".aclick img").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        alert($(this).data("link"));
        var link = $(this).data("link");
        console.log(link);
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#"  class="aclick">
    <img data-link="petroliumjelly.php" src="productsimgs/petroliumjelly.png" class="img-responsive" id="2">
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You click event must be on the image tag as well.

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
       $(".aclick img").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        alert($(this).attr("data-link"));
        var link = $(this).attr("data-link");// tried both 
        console.log(link);

    });

</script>
```

working Fiddle

```js
   $(".aclick img").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        alert($(this).attr("data-link"));
        var link = $(this).attr("data-link");// tried both 
        console.log(link);

    });
```

```html
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<a href="#"  class="aclick">
    <img data-link="petroliumjelly.php" src="productsimgs/petroliumjelly.png" class="img-responsive" id="2">
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

`Img` is the child element of `a`.so try with `$(this).children('img')` .And use use with `data('link')` instead of `data('data-link')`

```js
$(".aclick").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  alert($(this).children('img').attr("data-link"));
  var link = $(this).children('img').data("link"); // tried both 
  console.log(link);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" class="aclick">
  <img data-link="petroliumjelly.php" src="productsimgs/petroliumjelly.png" class="img-responsive" id="2">
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

this refers to the anchor tag not the image tag.
use this

```
$('.aclick img').attr("data-link");
```

Answer (score 0):

On `(.aclick).click()` `data-link` will return `undefined`, the `data-link` is on the image, get the image using [.find()](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/traversing_find.asp)

> The find() method returns descendant elements of the selected element.

To get the value of [data*](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_data.asp) use [.data()](https://api.jquery.com/data/)

> The data-* attributes is used to store custom data private to the page or application.
>
> .data() Store arbitrary data associated with the matched elements or return the value at the named data store for the first element in the set of matched elements.

```js
$(".aclick").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var link = $(this).find('img').data('link');
    console.log(link);
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#"  class="aclick">
    <img data-link="petroliumjelly.php" src="productsimgs/petroliumjelly.png" class="img-responsive" id="2">
</a>
```