# JQuery : Load a file in modal window

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am getting a file name on image click like this

```
<a href="#"  class="aclick" >
   <img data-link="petroliumjelly.php" src="productsimgs/petroliumjelly.png" class="img-responsive" id="2">
</a>
```

Now there pops up a modal window here and i have the page link **petroliumjelly.php** that i want to open in that  modal window .

```
  <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
       $(".aclick").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        var link = $(this).data("data-link");
        console.log(id);
        console.log(link);
        $('#modal_'+id).modal('show');
        $page = $(this).find('img').attr("data-link"); 
        //$('.modal-body')// load page her 
    });

</script>
```

How can i load that page in modal window please help .

Comment: Just over 20 minutes ago you asked a question and you got answers but you did not reply to a single one see here [Jquery : Access data-link attribute](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44046599/jquery-access-data-link-attribute) First accept answers

Comment: You don't accept answers but you keep on asking, no one will waste their time on you if you can't take 5 seconds to accept an answer

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jquery : Access data-link attribute](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44046599/jquery-access-data-link-attribute)

Comment: kindly review both questions and then let me know if its same .

Comment: @Sikander didn't the answer help solve your problem here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43187171/how-to-play-pause-video-on-scroll

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile thats a different question please review it .

Comment: I wanna know why was the answer not accepted in that question?

Comment: load the data like this $('.modal-body').load(petroliumjelly.php ,function(result){  $('#modal_).modal('show');  }); @Sikander

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile that was already accepted

Comment: when you ask a question, try to accept answers as this will help others in the future.

Comment: @Sikander do you knw how to accept answers?

Comment: @Sikander check the answer below, if you get errors let me know

Comment: if your query was solved please accept the answer below.

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile you were right this guy, doesn't accept answers.

Answer (score 1):

The `.aclick` doesn't have an `id` and `data-link`, they will return `undefined`, you need to find the image and get those from the image. To get the `data-link` use `().data('link')` not `data('data-link')`. To load the file in your modal you'll have to use [AJAX](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/ajax_get.asp) or the `.load()` to laod a file.

```
<script>
    $(".aclick").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $image = $(this).find('img');
        var id = $($image).attr('id');
        var link = $($image).data("link");
        console.log(id);
        console.log(link);
        $('#modal_'+id).modal('show');

        // using AJAX to fetch the file
        $.get(link, function (response) {
            $('.modal-body').html(response);
        })
    });
</script>
```

Or use `modal.load()` to load the file.

```
<script>
    $(".aclick").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $image = $(this).find('img');
        var id = $($image).attr('id');
        var link = $($image).data("link");
        console.log(id);
        console.log(link);

        // load the file
        $('.modal-body').load(link, function () {
            $('#modal_'+id).modal('show');
        })
    });
</script>
```